# Blanck facebook feed dialog box in titanium android

Tags: android, facebook, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to send a post to a selected facebook friend wall using the facebook feed API (as the graph API now only works in iphone for me and this is the reason : and this is the code i wrote :

```
//facebook initialization :
facebook = require('facebook');
facebook.setBubbleParent(false);
facebook.appid = 'xxxXXmyappIdXXxxx';
facebook.permissions = ['publish_stream', 'read_stream', 'email','user_photos', 'friends_photos', ' user_events', 'friends_events','user_likes'];
facebook.forceDialogAuth = true;


var data = {
    link: 'xxxXXXX mylink XXXXXxxxxxx'+Alloy.Globals.invitation_code,
    name: L('fb_invite_wall_post_name'),
    message: L('fb_invite_wall_post_msg')+Alloy.Globals.invitation_code+"'",
    caption: L('fb_invite_wall_post_caption'),
    picture: "xxxXXXX picture Url XXXXXxxxxxxlogo_big.png",
    description: L('fb_invite_wall_post_descrpt')+Alloy.Globals.invitation_code+"'.",
    to:this.user_uid
};
    //facebook.requestWithGraphPath(this.user_uid+'/feed', data, 'POST', showRequestResult);

    facebook.dialog("feed", data, showRequestResult);
```

i got a blanck facebook feed dialog box as shown here : 
[image]

sending the post to my own wall always works fine though but not to another friend's wall wether the condition for the "to" paramater :(The ID must be a friend who also uses your app) is respected or not.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround was to make an URL with parameters :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption 
  &link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

and use the openUrl() method to open it on browser.